# Using vector-tiles from MapBox in Telerik's RadMap component

Tags: wpf, telerik, mapbox

In mapbox studio we have made our own map style. One example is this one:

https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/airsupport/clqz9hc8e008x01pda4ji27pi.html?title=view&access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiYWlyc3VwcG9ydCIsImEiOiJjbHIyMHc4eXAwc3F2MnZ0M3N2cWtrbmgyIn0.5Z8aYouG1IiHvfUjyorsKA#5.42/55.061/11.442

I am trying to add this to RadMap using vector tiles instead of raster tiles. So far without luck.

If I use the MapBoxMapProvider:

```
<telerik:RadMap x:Name="map">
    <telerik:RadMap.Provider>
        <telerik:MapBoxMapProvider AccessToken="pk.eyJ1IjoiYWlyc3VwcG9ydCIsImEiOiJjbHIyMHc4eXAwc3F2MnZ0M3N2cWtrbmgyIn0.5Z8aYouG1IiHvfUjyorsKA">
        </telerik:MapBoxMapProvider>
    </telerik:RadMap.Provider>
</telerik:RadMap>
```

Then this just shows MapBox' standard maps. How do I get it to use our own map instead?

If I try to use the UriVectorTileMapProvider:

```
<telerik:RadMap x:Name="map">
    <telerik:RadMap.Provider>
        <telerik:UriVectorTileMapProvider UriTemplate="https://api.mapbox.com/v4/airsupport.clqz9hc8e008x01pda4ji27pi/{level}/{x}/{y}.mvt?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiYWlyc3VwcG9ydCIsImEiOiJjbHIyMHc4eXAwc3F2MnZ0M3N2cWtrbmgyIn0.5Z8aYouG1IiHvfUjyorsKA" />
    </telerik:RadMap.Provider>
</telerik:RadMap>
```

Then I am unsure, how the UriTemplate should be formatted. The example above does not work. And I cannot find any examples that shows the right way to do it with MapBox maps.

Anybody with experience in this?